# Nodes placement in knowledge map of Khan Academy

Tags: algorithms, networks

I have been through the Khan Academy [blog](http://bjk5.com/post/1664635835/constellation-knowledge) regarding construction of knowledge map.

[image]

However after going through it, it left me confused regarding how are they placing the nodes (hierarchically) and  how are they deciding the distance and coordinates between any two nodes. I read in that blog that every node is placed with a specific latitude and longitude; but it didn't mention how that lat/lng is decided. Are they deciding it manually or there is any algorithm they are using for it?

Can anyone please throw light on it.